# v11 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members') discord.js v11

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I want to connect to discord voice channel with discord.js as a user, and it works on some accounts but there is one account that shows this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'members')`
While using discord.js v11.

Here is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

const channelId = process.env.id
client.on("ready", () => {
  let channel = client.channels.cache.get(channelId);
  if(!channel) return console.log("Invalid channel id");
  channel.join().then(connection => {
  console.log("Successfully connected");
  });
});

client.login(process.env.token);
```

**(this is the code)**
**i am using discord.js v11.3.2**

Answer (score 0):

For one, member doesn't show up anywhere in this code snippet, and you will need to add some more code. I also noticed that at the 2nd line, `channelId` is spelt wrong, so that will cause an error. If you extend your code, I might be able to help. I am assuming that `members` is supposed to be `member`. So, try replacing `members` with `member`.

Comment: i edited the code, please read it and help me

Comment: I still dont see a member variable. Try updating your nodejs and discordjs version and running it again.